# Convert or compare "Unmanaged<NSString> and NSString

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct

I have a framework in Objective-C with this struct:

**VehicleClass.h**

```
struct VehicleStruct
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *const CAR;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *const MOTORCYCLE;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *const TRUCK;
};
```

**VehicleClass.m**

```
#import "VehicleClass.h"

const struct VehicleStruct Vehicle = {
    .CAR = @"CAR",
    .MOTORCYCLE = @"MOTORCYCLE",
    .TRUCK = @"TRUCK"
};
```

And in my **Contansts.h**

```
extern const struct VehicleStruct Vehicle;
```

Well, now I want get car value in my proyect using **swift**:

```
let carValueSwift = String(Vehicle.CAR)
```

In **console**:

> "Unmanaged NSString(_value: CAR)"

How can I solve this? I need get this value like NSString, because if then I want to compare in my framework:

`["CAR"  isEqual: carValueSwift]` Doesn´t work.

Thank you very much

Comment: Any reason why you are using `__unsafe_unretained` instead of `weak`?

Comment: __weak give next error: ARC forbids Objective-C objects in struct

Comment: Ah of course, you can't use `weak` in a struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `takeUnretainedValue()` the `Unmanaged<NSString>` is converted
to `NSString` (without taking ownership), and this can simply be
cast to a Swift `String`:

```
let carValueSwift = Vehicle.CAR.takeUnretainedValue() as String
print(carValueSwift)
```

Comment: Good answer ;) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Well, I found solution:**

```
let car: Unmanaged<NSString> = Vehicle.CAR

let carString = convertCfTypeToString(car)
```

**Function:**

```
func convertCfTypeToString(cfValue: Unmanaged<NSString>!) -> String?
{
   let value = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(
       cfValue.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as CFStringRef
   if CFGetTypeID(value) == CFStringGetTypeID(){
       return value as String
   } else {
       return nil
   }
}
```

If anyone knows other way to avoid use `convertCfTypeToString:` method, please, let me know...